# python/django: correct way of calling subclass method

Tags: python, django

I have a class `BaseUser` and a class `RegisteredUser` (`AbstractBaseUser` is a django class)

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    #std properties of a base user

class RegisteredUser(BaseUser):
    def send_welcome_email(self):
      #send the email
```

A user can be invited to the platform, then she gets a TempLogin:

```
class TempLogin(models.Model):
   login_code:  models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   user:   models.ForeignKey(BaseUser, unique=True)
```

Thus the user has a login_code associated with it. It needs to be on BaseUser because other user types are supported.

Then, when the user arrives to the platform with her code, I look up the code, and get the user:

```
     code  = TemporaryLoginCode.objects.get(code=pk)
     user  = code.user
     user.send_welcome_email()
```

The last bit breaks because `send_welcome_email()` is on `RegisteredUser`, not `BaseUser`.

I can't move `send_welcome_email()` to `RegisteredUser` apparently (third party code).

How can I have `user` become a `RegisteredUser` instance? Do I need to do another lookup on the DB, with the user id as key, in order to retrieve its `RegisteredUser` instance? Or is there another way?

I know I can't use super() as `RegisteredUser` is a subclass of `BaseUser`, not the other way around.

Comment: Why not make `TempLogin.user` a foreign key to `RegisteredUser`?

Comment: Because I can't (as mentioned in the description), it's third party code I have to support. Also, an invitation could be extended to other user types which are not RegisteredUser but which also are subclass of BaseUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You have defined the relationship as to BaseUser. It sounds like the send_welcome_email should be on RegisteredUser, as you are registered, and you get a welcome email. I would suggest when a user gets registered temporarily, they are not a registered user. Why not have a class TemporaryUser, which has a method send_temp_welcome_email, and have your code do this

```
class TempUser(BaseUser):
     def send_temp_welcome_email(self):
     #send the tempemail

class TempLogin(models.Model):
   login_code:  models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   user:   models.ForeignKey(TempUser, unique=True)

 code  = TemporaryLoginCode.objects.get(code=pk)
 user  = code.user
 user.send_temp_welcome_email()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to def the `send_welcome_email()` in BaseUser (if you have all you need there) and def same method in RegisteredUser calling `super().send_welcome_email()`?

I didn't understand which code is thirdy part because you have your BaseUser and you mentioned that RegisteredUser is thirdy part but is inherited from you BaseUser.